# Left Join + count + sum on MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, count, sum

This question is similar to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940591/sum-on-mysql-left-join-with-relation-1x/36941078#36941078). But with several variants (I have probems with advanced JOINs and I couldn't find any usefull info in the forum).

Again, I changed the name of the tables, fields and values, keeping just the structure of my data base for you to understand.

Now, let's suppouse I have this (and I can't change the structure):

.

### People

```
ID | AGE | COUNTRY 
1  |  25 |   usa   
2  |  46 |   mex   

...
```

.

### Foods

```
ID | PERSON_ID | CATEGORY | FOOD       | UNITS
1  |     1     | fruit    | apple      |   2
2  |     1     | fruit    | grape      |  24
3  |     1     | fruit    | orange     |   5
3  |     1     | fast     | pizza      |   1
4  |     1     | fast     | hamburguer |   3
5  |     1     | cereal   | corn       |   2

...
```

.

But I have hundreds of `people` all with their relation in table `foods`, about eight categories on `foods` and each category has 4 to 24 `food`.

Fine, currently I am using a code similar to this one:

```
SELECT p.*, SUM(f.units) as orapple
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN foods f
ON f.person_id = p.id
  AND f.food in('apple','orange')
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id
```

To get this:

```
ID | AGE | COUNTRY | ORAPPLE
1  |  25 |   usa   |    7
```

Note that `orapple` in the result is the sum of the numbers on `units`, specifically, where `food` is equal to 'orange' and 'apple'.

Now, what I need it to add the number of each category, example, I need this:

```
ID | AGE | COUNTRY | ORAPPLE | FRUIT | FAST | CEREAL
1  |  25 |   usa   |    7    |   3   |  2   |   1
```

Comment: sum(category='fruit')

Comment: Can you hardcode all the given categories, or does it need to be dynamic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I can hard code the categories (adding comments in other parts to remember to change the code in case of a new category).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the result from

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM foods;
```

to construct the following query:

```sql
SELECT p.*,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f.food in ('apple','orange') THEN f.units ELSE 0 END) as orapple,
  COUNT(f.category='fruit'  OR NULL) AS fruits,
  COUNT(f.category='fast'   OR NULL) AS fast,
  COUNT(f.category='cereal' OR NULL) AS cereal 
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN foods f
ON f.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71e12/21

Search the web or SO for [pivot-table](/questions/tagged/pivot-table) to find more examples.

Comment: Nice, This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @KennyLajara, i just realized that you are using `LEFT JOIN`. So i changed the solution to prevent NULLs in the result. You can see the difference in sqlfiddle.

Comment: Ohh, I see, Thanks. I really appreciate your answer. The problem was that I didn't know CASE WHEN. But now everything is solved. Thanks =D